# Does the damage from Ahris "Orb of Deception" depend on more than the raw AP?

Tags: league-of-legends

When Ahri fires her *Orb of Deception* on some minions, I noticed that the damage output isn't always the same.

Assuming both situations are with the same Items (so no change in AP and MP) it's sometimes the case that I can kill caster miniions with one combo (so the orb hits both times). Then without changing AP and MP sometimes the caster minions are left with some HP (also the orb hits both times).

Is there anything else affecting my damage on those minions? Or is it that I maybe just have sometimes a few more AP from any sort of Buff or because I used my ignite (I have the +5 AP when Ignite on CD Mastery for Ahri )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minions gain health over time, so if you barely 1-shot them now you won't 1-shot them in the next cycle which is nicely explained on this page: http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/166-game-play-guide-last-hitting

> Minions have an "Upgrade Cycle" that activates every 3 minutes. Despite spawning only at 1:30 the cycle already begins at 0:00. Meaning that after 3 minion waves a minion's power and gold worth is already higher than the first 3 waves.
>
> Melee
> Health: 445 (+20 per cycle)
> Armor: 0 (+2 per cycle)
> Magic Resistance: 0 (+1.25 per cycle)
>
> Caster
> Health: 280 (+15 per cycle)
> Armor: 0 (+1.25 per cycle)
> Magic Resistance: 0 (+2 per cycle)
>
> Siege
> Health: 700 (+27 per cycle)
> Armor: 15 (+3 per cycle)
> Magic Resistance: 0 (+3 per cycle)
>
> Super
> Health: 1500 (+200 per cycle)
> Armor: 30
> Magic Resistance: -30

Ahris damage is only influenced by level/AP and wether you hit opponents in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

The damages are always the same with a fix AP

Could be their life increased over time or ...

- Ignite Masteries
- Hero like Sona walking around (bonus AP)
- Hero with WOTA walking around
- Hero with abyssal scepter lowering the MR (-20)
- AP/lvl Runes
- Magic Pen Boots => same AP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Ahri's](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions/103/ahri_the_9_tails_fox) Orb of Deception does AP damage on the way out, and true damage (damage that hits full regardless of the opponent's armor/magic resist) on the way back, so the damage discrepancy between hitting minions with the orb on the way out and hitting them on the way back could mean a great deal if the minions have any amount of magic resist.

It's also worth noting that the bonus damage for both the orb going out and coming back scale off of AP (+.33).

Comment: He said in the Question that the Orb hits both times so this doesn't matter in this situation.